# Android Surfaceflinger - how to access functions

Tags: android, surfaceflinger

Android 5.0.1 (Galaxy S4 i9505 Imperium rom): I'm trying to access various functions of SurfaceFlinger with the aim of either resizing HW Layers or accessing each HW Layer and saving as a bitmap or displaying on a separate Surface (initiated from JAVA), but Android Studio (1.3, with gradle 2.5) just reports 'undefined reference' to ****.

I've pulled the shared libraries mentioned in Android.mk that I found online which are pixelflinger, cutils, log, dl, hardware, hardware_legacy, utils, GLESv1, GLESv2, binder, ui, gui, powermanager, c, skia.

Can anyone help?

Comment: SurfaceFlinger is a service that you communicate with via Binder IPC. The various functions are non-public and often restricted, so it's unlikely you will be able to do anything useful from an app. See [screenrecord](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/lollipop-mr1-release/cmds/screenrecord/) for an example of a program that accesses SurfaceFlinger directly.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  I can see what you mean.  The problem I'm getting is that I am using:

Comment: Fadden, thanks for your prompt reply.  I can see what you mean.  The problem I'm getting is that I am using: SurfaceComposerClient scc;
        status_t err = scc.setSize(ibinder,500,500);  I have typed 'ibinder' as an IBinder is expected.  Is there any way I can get the IBinder of a 'layer' - I can get the ID etc from a dumpsys of surfaceflinger but how do I use this with the IBinder part of setSize??  I also tried to use parts of the actual source code of surfaceflinger.cpp but just kept on getting various errors, for example including 'layer.h' introduced 'bufferqueue?' errors in layer.h